# Helm release "cert-manager" was created but has a failed status

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm, cert-manager

Warning says I should run "helm" command and investigate the error. What command is that? https://phoenixnap.com/kb/helm-commands-cheat-sheet

```
╷
│ Warning: Helm release "cert-manager" was created but has a failed status. Use the `helm` command to investigate the error, correct it, then run Terraform again.
│ 
│   with module.cert-manager.helm_release.helm_release,
│   on ../../../../../modules/helm/main.tf line 94, in resource "helm_release" "helm_release":
│   94: resource "helm_release" "helm_release" {
│ 
╵
```

### helm list

Requested output of kube-system

`helm -n kube-system list`

```
NAME            NAMESPACE   REVISION    UPDATED                                 STATUS  CHART               APP VERSION
cert-manager    kube-system 1           2022-08-23 14:15:50.882082 -0700 PDT    failed  cert-manager-v1.5.4 v1.5.4
```

### helm main.tf

```
resource "helm_release" "helm_release" {
  name        = var.helm_release_name
  description = var.helm_release_description
  repository  = var.helm_repo
  chart       = var.helm_chart_name
  version     = var.helm_chart_version

  create_namespace = var.helm_create_namespace
  namespace        = var.helm_release_namespace

  recreate_pods = var.helm_recreate_pods
  atomic        = var.helm_atomic
  wait          = var.helm_wait
  wait_for_jobs = var.helm_wait_for_jobs

  cleanup_on_fail = var.helm_cleanup_on_fail

  values = var.helm_values

  # Default timeout of 300 sometimes not enough.
  timeout = 900

  dynamic "set" {
    for_each = var.helm_set
    content {
      name  = set.key
      value = set.value
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: helm -n <k8s_ns> list

can you share your `resource "helm_release" "helm_release"` entire block?

Comment: @gumelaragum See above for the edit

Comment: you can delete the helm release right? as it failed and or debugging with it

Comment: You're talking about `cert-manager`? Yes I an delete it. But every time I recreate it, it's ending up in this failed state.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might miss a few sets, here's what worked for me in EKS:

```
  set {
    name  = "serviceAccount.name"
    value = var.service_account
  }

  set {
    name  = "serviceAccount.annotations.eks\\.amazonaws\\.com/role-arn"
    value = aws_iam_role.this.arn
  }

  set {
    name  = "installCRDs"
    value = "true"
  }
```